# how to connect sql server over the internet

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using Windows server 2012 r2. I have installed sql server 2008 r2 on that server. I am trying to access that sql database form my PC. Using Ip address of the server and port no 1433 to access but it is showing me network related instance specific error.

I am also trying to login on server in sql server 2008 database using Ip address of server and default port no example: 192.160.45.345,1433 but I am not able to login. It is also showing me network related instance specific error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbKSj.png). Please suggest me any solution

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

As it said in the error message, the SQL Server might haven't been configured to allow remote connections, that's the reason you cannot connect to it over the internet.

Try this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191464(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your response 
I have configured SQL server to allow remote connections but problem is that I am not able to ping windows server 2012 from my computer it is showing "request time out" message. So can I access Sql server while I am not able to ping Windows server from my computer? if not is there any way to access sql server( which is on windows server)?